# Incorrect Printing String With Whitespace from ArrayList

Tags: java, console-application

I play this game where you can collect HUNDREDS of power ups, and the only way to know what they do without memorizing them is to look them up. Because of this, I am trying to make myself a "assistant" program where I can type in the name of the power up and get the effect of it.

Below is the full code with useless parts taken out. Examples of outputs are below. The problem should be fairly obvious if you look at the outputs. What ways could I use to fix this problem, or what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgMain {

 // // *** ------------*** and any variations indicate a change of importance or use

  public static ArrayList<String> itemlist; // ArrayList of items to cycle through to see if item exists in database.

  static {
     itemlist = new ArrayList<String>();

        itemlist.add("genericitem"); // testing item
        itemlist.add("exit"); // allows for internal program exit
        itemlist.add("debuglist"); // allows to print every item in "itemlist" for debug

        // ***-------------------------------------------------***

        itemlist.add(0, "thisitem hasaspace");

  }

static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String item = " " // variable to store name of item

    System.out.println("Enter an item name to check the database.");
    System.out.println("Enter 'exit' to quit the program.");
    System.out.println();

    while(true) {
        System.out.print("Item Name: ");
        item = console.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", " ");


        /**
         * ONLY FINDS FIRST WORD, even after removal of spaces.
         */
            //DEBUG
        System.out.print("\n     DEBUG: " + item + "\n");

        if (itemlist.contains(item)) { // cycle through database

            displayItemProperties(item); // find item and print properties
            System.out.println();

        } else { // declares if the item isn't found in database
            System.out.println("That item does not exist.");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

static void displayItemProperties(String item) {

    /**
     * Item names must be in LOWERCASE and have NO SPACES.
     */

    // GENERIC IF STATEMENT
    // Easy copy/paste to add new items

    /*

    if (item.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("");
    }

    */
    // **----------------------------------**

    if (item.equals("genericitem")) {
        System.out.println("A generic item.");
    }

    if (item.equals("debuglist")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(itemlist.get(i));
        }
    }

    if (item.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("Application Terminating...");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // ***------------------------------------------------------***

    if (item.equals("thisitem hasaspace")) {
        System.out.println("If a name has a space, it wont show up correctly...");
    }

    // introduce new item declarations here     
}
}
```

This is an example output of something entered WITHOUT A SPACE:

```
Enter an item name to check the database.
Enter 'exit' to quit the program.

Item Name: genericitem

 DEBUG: genericitem
A generic item.

Item Name: exit

 DEBUG: exit
Application Terminating...
```

and this is what happens when a name WITH A SPACE is used:

```
Enter an item name to check the database.
Enter 'exit' to quit the program.

Item Name: thisitem hasaspace

 DEBUG: thisitem
That item does not exist.

Item Name:

 DEBUG: hasaspace
That item does not exist.

Item Name: exit

 DEBUG: exit
Application Terminating...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Scanner` class by default uses any whitespace as a delimiter pattern. This includes a regular `SPACE`. So when you call `Scanner.next()`, it pulls the next token, and **thisite hasaspace** is 2 separate tokens because a space is a default delimiter.

Instead of calling `Scanner.next()`, try calling `Scanner.nextLine()`:

```
    item = console.nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", " ");
```